# Wifi problems with Linux Mint and Android

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, linux-mint, android

Since I installed Linux Mint 15, every time I connect my laptop on the wifi the internet connection on my Android phone suffers a LOT (very slow). The internet on my laptop works fine. My router is a Medialink MWN-WAPR300N. The phone is a Nexus 4.

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

Power management is off (as reported by iwconfig).

Apparently my driver is  bcmwl-kernel-source Version: 6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu6

Comment: Can you elaborate on "suffer". Is it having trouble connecting, low signal, general slowness?

Comment: What is your wireless card? lspci -vnn | grep - i net, please post output.

Answer (score 0):

Check out installing **ndiswrapper**. It is a driver which allows you to use windows drivers. This will allow you to use the specific wifi driver for your computer. Ubuntu wifi drivers are open source and generic. They can cause a lot of problems. Install ndiswrapper and your specific driver and you should be good. Post back if you need help.

**NOTE**: I have installed ndiswrapper but I have never needed to use it.

Comment: I'm using the wl drivers. Those should be better since they are from Broadcom directly, no?